# How to switch to definition of a function in 'Debugger' tab in firefox from 'console' tab?

Tags: debugging, firefox, browser, developer-tools, javascript-debugger

I have a function name. I want to go to the definition of the function in 'Debugger' tab of firefox for debugging purpose. The way given in the firefox debugger tutorials is that either I have to search for the function in the debugger tab globally or else I have to open the file in which the function resides and get the function definition. In my case, I am not sure where the code will reside and I can use the global search to get it, but it takes a huge time to get since my code base is large.
In chrome, we can type the function name in the console and it will return the first line or a small part of the function definition in the console. clicking on it will lead to the definition of the function in 'Sources' tab. I want to know is there any similar way in firefox or any other shortcut specific to firefox for this?

Note : If I type the function name in 'console' tab in firefox, it returns that the typed value is a function. And in it, if I type functionName.toSource(), it returns the full code. But I want to keep the break point on the source code. So, I want to switch from console to debugger tab in firefox to keep the break point for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend placing a `debugger` statement in the function's parent scope, then when you open devtools and load the page the source debugger should stop at that statement. Then you can switch to the console and call that function.

Comment: If it's my development machine code, I can insert the debugger statement. But in live production environment, I cannot do it Nick.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware. I'm pretty sure Firefox doesn't have this feature, you should just search all files with ctrl/command-shift/f, search the specific file with ctrl/command-f, or search the original codebase on disk which would likely be faster. Or use another browser to find it, then open that file in Firefox's debugger tab.